# How to create web api methods?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am developing one restfull wep api application. I am new to the world of web api and little confused about http verbs. My tasks is to write services using web api2. I have one table in sql server and i am trying to do basic crud operation around this table. I want to send data in json format and return data as json. For example http://localhost:26079/api/User_Creation/1 returns data in json format as expected. My task is to host above method in iis so that anyone can access that method to retrieve data. I am confused suppose if i want to insert some data to db then what would be the method? I have below code in controllera and i am able to insert data.

```
            public void Post(Noor_Users users)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    entityObject.Noor_Users.Add(users);
                    int result = entityObject.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

When i insert data my url will be http://localhost:26079/ but how can i expose my insert data method to outside world? My requirement is as follows.

```
URL:/user_creation
method:post
Request:parameters such as fname,lname as json
Response:0 for success 1 for failure and data(unique id assigned to each user)
```

may i get some help on this? Thank for consideration.

Comment: when you create a new WebApi project you will be having auto generated controllers like Account,Home. Have a look at it you can understand abotu the verbs

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have one doubt. I am using angularjs as front end. So for example i have   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model) this method id used to save data. How can i call this method from angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When considering REST it is important to understand and design it as you are taking actions against a resource at the location, and not like making a remote function call.

So I would suggest to have API as - 
http://localhost:26079/api/User

instead of - http://localhost:26079/api/User_Creation

In order to adhere to REST principals.

Doing this I am very clearly stating that the user of the api will be able to perform operations on the resource (*which is a User in this case*) using different verbs viz. `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

See some examples on using the API  -

- If I need to get a user with Id 1, I would call api like,  http://localhost:26079/api/User/1 with `GET` request
- To create a new user, I would call,  http://localhost:26079/api/User with `POST` request and send the user information in request body
- To delete a user with id 1, I would call  http://localhost:26079/api/User/1 with `Delete` request
- To update a user data with Id 1, call  http://localhost:26079/api/User/1 with `PUT` request and send the updated user information in request body

Please note here that we are using just a **single endpoint** to perform different operations on our *User* by changing different HTTP verbs.

The default asp.net web api template gives some good hint on how to declare different verb methods e.g. -

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>/1
    public User Get(int id)
    {
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]User user)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/1
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]User user)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/1
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

There is some good information [here](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337268/some-doubts-about-a-proper-rest-api-design/337270#337270) on designing restful api.

Comment: thanks for your post. I got my basic understandings in a clean way. Still I have few points. Instead of void can i have other return types? can i have multiple post in one controller? If so how to distinguish between them?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole: Added a discussion and a series on some good stuff on api design. Hope that would help :)

Comment: Yes i will go through. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your emthod from Angular, you can just use $http.post() method:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) you can find more information.

Comment: Thank you for your response.